# How many possible functions?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Take $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ to $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

How many such functions satisfy the cardinality of the pre-image of the set $\{3\}$ is equal to $3$.

I thought it would be $35$, i.e :$7\choose{3}$ however my book is getting $8960$, could someone explain where this extra factor of $256$ is coming from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to choose the pre-image of $\{3\}$. Given that choice, you still need to decide where the other four elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ map. For each one, there are four choices of where it maps ($0,1,2,$ or $4$), so there are $4^4$ choices for where those four elements not in the pre-image of $\{3\}$ map. Thus there are $\binom{7}{3}\cdot 4^4$ possible functions satisfying that the preimage of $\{3\}$ has cardinality $3$.